# Why this Javascript runs once in Firefox and Explorer, but 3 times in Opera?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have following file (not including PHP here as I know it works fine):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function stopUpload(){
     document.getElementById("adpictureholder").innerHTML += 'test';
     return true;   
}
window.top.window.stopUpload();
</script>

<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
```

Basically, I'm uploading the picture to the server inside an iFrame (so that page doesn't reload).

Why does `stopUpload()` run 3 times in Opera while working once in other browsers?

Comment: Is this all of the relevant code? If so, `adpictureholder` isn't referring to anything. Another quirk that *probably* isn't causing your issue but should be changed is that you are calling `window.top.window.stopUpload()`. You should just use `window.stopUpload()` or `stopUpload()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a complete file upload solution like `dropzone.js`.

Answer (score 0):

its because of given `src="#"` in iframe. remove it or change it to `""` or any other specific url.

```
<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
```